# Authentication in GraphQL servers

Tags: authentication, graph, authorization, jwt

How to properly handle authentication in GraphQL servers?

Is it ok to pass a JWT token at the Authorization header of query/mutation requests?

Should I use something from GraphQL specification?

Stateless solutions is preferable.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication in Relay & GraphQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618385/authentication-in-relay-graphql)

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I was wondering the same thing for sometime,
but apparently authentication is out of the scope of what GraphQL is trying to accomplish (see the conversations on [Github](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/113)).

But there are solutions such as [this](https://medium.com/the-graphqlhub/graphql-and-authentication-b73aed34bbeb#.ih6z307rf) which handles it with sessions.

Assuming you use [express-graphql](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql), here is what you can do.

```
import graphQLHTTP from 'express-graphql'
app.use(`/graphql`, [aValidationFunction, graphQLHTTP(options)])

function aValidationFunction(req, res, next) {
  const { authorization } = req.headers
  // Do your validation here by using redis or whatever
  if (validUser) {
    return next()
  } else {
    return res.status(403)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether your GraphQL consumer is a webapp or mobileapp.

If it is a webapp, then I would recommend sticking with session-cookie-based authentication since most popular web frameworks support this, and you also get CSRF protection.

If it is a mobileapp, then you will want JWT. You can try manually getting a cookie header from login response, and put stuff this "cookie" in your next request, but I had problem that some proxy servers strip off this "cookie", leaving your request unauthenticated. So as you said, including JWT in every authenticated request (GraphQL request) is the way to go.